# How to add a cron expression to a message processor in WSO2 ESB

Tags: cron, wso2, cronexpression, wso2-esb

I'd like to create a new Message Processor in WSO 2 (Scheduled Messaging Forward Processor). This processor should include the property "cronExpression" which I set to "*0-59 * * * **" (without quotation marks).

Saving the processor leads to the following exception: *RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver Error setting cron expression: Unexpected end of expression*.

However, I'm quite sure that there is nothing wrong with the expression.

Any ideas why this fails?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quartz OpenSymphony](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/Documentation.html) is used as the cron scheduler and you can find the cron expression tutorial for Quartz OpenSymphony from [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html).

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial mentioned by Thilini explains everything.